# flutter and getstream.io: the messages flickering

Tags: flutter, dart, getstream-io

I am currently working on a Flutter project where there is a chat made with getstream.io.

The problem is that the chat messages flicker and sometimes are not displayed at all.

Here is my Chatpage:

```
class ChannelPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChannelPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.channel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Channel channel;

  @override
  // ignore: prefer_expression_function_bodies
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final name = channel.name?.replaceAll('| frozen', '') ?? '';
    final shortenName = name.length > 23 ? '${name.substring(0, 23)}...' : name;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: StreamChannelHeader(
        title: Text(
          shortenName,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
        ),
        subtitle: Container(),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Center(
              child: CustomStreamChannelAvatar(
                channel: channel,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: _buildChat(),
          ),
          StreamMessageInput(showCommandsButton: false),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildChat() {
    return StreamMessageListView(
      messageBuilder: (context, details, messages, defaultMessage) {
        return defaultMessage.copyWith(
          showFlagButton: false,
          showEditMessage: false,
          showCopyMessage: false,
          showDeleteMessage: false,
          showReplyMessage: false,
          showThreadReplyMessage: false,
          showPinButton: false,
          showReactions: false,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The whole thing was unfortunately implemented by other developers and I have to fix it now, this is also the first time I work with GetStream.

However, I don't think there is an error here, I think it will be somewhere else, maybe someone of you has an idea what could be the reason. Thank you!